# How to get balance of enterprise address

Tags: blockfrost, cardano-address

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/~1addresses~1%7Baddress%7D~1extended/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/%7E1addresses%7E1%7Baddress%7D%7E1extended/get)

I am using above blockfrost api to get address balance.

However, it isn't working with enterprise address, I am getting 504 error for enterprise address.

I also tried https://api.koios.rest/#post-/address_assets, getting same 504 error.

How can I get balance for enterprise address?

Comment: This endpoint also works with enterprise addresses for me.

Comment: Can you let me know address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint is working with enterprise addresses too (as well as with payment credentials or any other addresses).

```
$ curl -s  -H "project_id: ..." \
   https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/addresses/addr1v8px4syex8e07e6c2ucfheh27t2tcxxjm5el22g0cw32m5g77jc7x \
   | jq
{
  "address": "addr1v8px4syex8e07e6c2ucfheh27t2tcxxjm5el22g0cw32m5g77jc7x",
  "amount": [
    {
      "unit": "lovelace",
      "quantity": "17374229558"
    }
  ],
  "stake_address": null,
  "type": "shelley",
  "script": false
}

$
```

As you can see in the example above, this address does not contain any `stake_address`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you check this address ? ```addr1v9u7va2sktlnz8dp3qadpnxxlv4m03672jy6elmntlxxs7q9nnwl9``` Why is it not working?

Comment: It works fine for me. When you open https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/addresses/addr1v9u7va2sktlnz8dp3qadpnxxlv4m03672jy6elmntlxxs7q9nnwl9 what do you get?

Comment: Oh, ```/addresses/{address}```api is working. I was trying ```/addresses/${address}/extended```

Comment: Not sure why, .../extended also works for enterprise addresses generally, but not for this particular one. Maybe related to the high number of transactions, so could be a bug in blockfrost.